# Returning a response before redirecting to followup event

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

My use case is that I would like to offer a reminder option to the user. So,...

- Agent: "Would you like me to remind you?"
- User: "Yes"
- Agent: "In how many minutes?"
- User: "10"
- Agent: "Awesome, I have set up your reminder."
- [10 mins pass]
- Agent: "Ding dong! time's up."

I am setting the remind_time and responding with that confirmation response but having a challenge figuring out how to invoke a function to check the time, which would not be a user-triggered intent.

I was pursuing using conv.followup() but what I get from the AoG doc is that a single response will be sent back for a request AND only done so after the specified followup event has been executed. So, this is not possible for fulfillment of an intent:

1. Set remind_time value
2. Respond with confirmation
3. Timeout for remind_time
4. Respond with alert

At the end of [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dialogflow/KfDMf_DRuw4;context-place=topicsearchin/dialogflow/trigger$20event) thread, there's some discussion of workarounds but didn't help me much.

Any insight, but especially a code example, would be extremely helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible this way.

Intents only get triggered based on a user action - typically what they say. `conv.followup()` is used in fairly rare cases - to trigger another Intent that would, effectively, replace the current one being handled.

It sounds like you more want a [push notification](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications). This has some limitations, however, most notably that you can only send notifications to mobile devices at the moment, not Smart Speakers.

While there are some other options, they are probably even less desirable (at least to your users).

You cannot just trigger another event at the relevant time. That is actually what the notification method somewhat does.

Keep in mind that your webhook must return a reply within about 5 seconds, and after that time all further responses are ignored. One way to workaround this is to send a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) to play some audio (even a silent audio) for some period of time. When the Media finishes, it will automatically trigger an event for your Action. This lets you check if the alarm time has been reached and, if not, send another Media Response.

This latter point, however, has a number of drawbacks. Your users can easily interrupt your Media playback and cancel it - in which case you never get the re-request. Your users also can't use the Assistant for anything else in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, not sure push not's will do. What if I didn't try to use followup to chain off the set reminder intent? Would there be any other way to invoke an action (to regularly check if remind_time was met)?